# Include Reference in project file structure

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012

Sorry, a bit of a noobish question here...spent an hour on Google and in MSs help documents, my head appears to be in the wrong place, I can't figure this out.

I have a C# project set up in Visual Studio 2012 that has references to a few .dlls that I have on my own hard drive (NetOffice .dlls to be specific, for Excel Interop).  I've been adding them by right clicking on my references folder, going to Add Reference and then going to Browse to find the files.  At that point they are included and everything works as expected on my side.

The problem occurs when I share the project.  I'm using Git to keep the project coordinated between myself and a couple team members.  I'll run my commit and push it then have my teammate do his pull.  Everything shows up on his computer correctly, but when we open up the project it tells me that the NetOffice .dlls are missing.

I'm guess that this is because the files are only linked locally on my computer, but I can't figure out, for the life of me, how to make the .dlls exist in the file structure so that they travel with the project when I push it.

We have a few NuGet packages we use as well, and they seem to work just fine after being transferred.  I've also gone into the .dll properties for NetOffice and turned "Copy Local" to `true`, yet it's still not included.

All I want is to be able to link references and then send the whole thing (dlls included) to my teammate, what am I doing wrong?  I figured I would want to simply include the .dlls in the project structure but...  I'm just not understanding something.  Any help please?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?? People, if you're downvoting, at least have the courtesy to explain the downvote!

Comment: Because, @Christian, clearly the last four hours of time I spent researching the answer before posting didn't count?  Lord forgive me for being new I guess... (sorry, a tad unprofessional, but it's more than kind of frustrating to ask an honest question, described as best I can, and then get downvoted.)

Comment: If you have non-public dependencies that change a lot, it might be worth to consider creating a local NuGet repository. That way developers can get resolve the required dependencies using NuGet and the created binaries from the dependencies do not have to be added to the source control. If the dependencies are rather stable though, adding them to the source control is generally not a problem.

Comment: @poke - That does make some sense.  For now I'm using some very stable binaries, but when we start using team dependencies, I'll have to make sure I do this (or something very similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Create a folder in the file system at the same level as the solution file.
2 Copy the external dll's to that folder.
3 Add a Solution Folder tho the solution.
4 Add each dll to the the solution folder using add existing item
5 Reference the Dll's in the solution

The steps 3 and 4 aren't really necessary, but they help to keep things organized.

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason I had dismissed that idea early on.  I think I'd recently had an experience where doing that hadn't helped because the file path was not relative.  This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not good practise to include binaries in your git repository, doing so will solve your problem.

The quick fix could be to create `lib` directories in sensible locations within your repository (I'm not a C# developer but Gama Felix's suggestion seems correct).

Then commit these folders and push to the server.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do what Gama said, but I wonder, what would you say the best practice is?

Comment: Much better practise to use a package manager of some sort. My experience is largely with Java ([Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)) and Ruby ([Bundler](http://gembundler.com/)) so I can't give you a solid suggestion for C# - although I think NuGet might work in a similar way. Essentially, you want to separate your code from its dependencies.

Comment: You should call that folder `lib` or something though, as the `bin` dir contains the files generated by Visual Studio when compiling.

Comment: Hmm.  I've only ever used NuGet to connect to online dependencies...  I have to admit I'm not terribly familiar with it, but I'll give it a look to see if this can solve this problem in the future. @poke - Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your source control root folder is called **SourceRoot** 
and your solution files are under a folder called **JaySolutionFolder**
I prefer:
Adding a new folder to your source control, under SourceRoot, called **SharedDlls** 
Copy all *external Dlls* to this Folder.
Add this dll references form SharedDlls to your project.
Commit this folder
Now your teammates have to get JaySolutionFolder & SharedDlls to compile the sources.
Later this SharedDlls could be target directory of Build process (Using tools like [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) Bulid, [NANT](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) or else)
This will be a way to minimize team based development problems.
In release and software installation, you can use *installers* or *software package builders* like [installshield](http://www.installshield.com/) or [Visual Studio Setup Package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353) or  ... to solve external dlls problem 
Hop this helps.